# is there way to query current row values combined with a filtered set of results from the same table with in a PostgreSQL function

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

I've got query which works as expected and now i would like to turn in to a function which can update values in a second table when a change occurs in a row of the source table.

The query is comparing the value of every row to a reference value in the same table

This code worked when it was a query when i changed into a function, gives an error and i can't work out why.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.____MBPX_CurrentOverEv(in_reading readings)
    RETURNS numeric
    LANGUAGE 'sql'

AS $BODY$

SELECT 

(r1.node1_value/r1.ev_value)-(r2.node1_value/r2.ev_value) as n1
,(r1.node2_value/r1.ev_value)-(r2.node2_value/r2.ev_value) as n2
,(r1.node3_value/r1.ev_value)-(r2.node3_value/r2.ev_value) as n3
,(r1.node4_value/r1.ev_value)-(r2.node4_value/r2.ev_value) as n4
,(r1.node5_value/r1.ev_value)-(r2.node5_value/r2.ev_value) as n5
,(r1.node6_value/r1.ev_value)-(r2.node6_value/r2.ev_value) as n6

FROM in_reading r1
full join in_reading r2 on r1.instrument_id =r2.instrument_id
where r2.reading_type = 'reference' 


;
    $BODY$;
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR:  relation "in_reading" does not exist
LINE 18: FROM in_reading r1
              ^
SQL state: 42P01
Character: 540
```

Comment: Are you trying to pass the table name as a parameter to the function?

Comment: i think that is what i need to do, ideally i only what the function the one row which is changed not the whole data set

Comment: Unless you're going to do something with the table name, I think you don't need to include it as an argument to the function -- you can have the function take no arguments

Comment: However, I think you might be better off just making a view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be better off just making a view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ____MBPX_CurrentOverEv
AS
SELECT 
(r1.node1_value/r1.ev_value)-(r2.node1_value/r2.ev_value) as n1
,(r1.node2_value/r1.ev_value)-(r2.node2_value/r2.ev_value) as n2
,(r1.node3_value/r1.ev_value)-(r2.node3_value/r2.ev_value) as n3
,(r1.node4_value/r1.ev_value)-(r2.node4_value/r2.ev_value) as n4
,(r1.node5_value/r1.ev_value)-(r2.node5_value/r2.ev_value) as n5
,(r1.node6_value/r1.ev_value)-(r2.node6_value/r2.ev_value) as n6
FROM in_reading r1
full join in_reading r2 on r1.instrument_id =r2.instrument_id
where r2.reading_type = 'reference';
```

This might be good enough for you, unless you were planning on adding more clauses dynamically (like `r1.node6_value/r1.ev_value)....`)

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](http://enterprisedb.com)